# Tagging noun adjunct or attributive noun using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I want to use NLTK to recognize the difference between "red dress" and "dress shoes".  The part of speech is the same for both, and none of the taggers I have tried have worked.

I'm aware that POS tagger can only pick up on one token at a time, which poses some problems.  I'm very new to NLTK, and I'm sure I'm just missing something very basic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Spacy](https://spacy.io/)

```
pip install spacy
```

Here is a small example to parse and visualize `"dress shoes"`:

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc = nlp("dress shoes")
displacy.serve(doc, style='dep')
```

[image: red dress]
[image: dress shoes]

The relation between `red` (adjective) to `dress` (noun) is an *adjectival modifier* (`amod`), while the relation between `dress` (noun) and `shoes` (noun) is a *compound*.

These can be accessed via `token.dep_` (for dependencies) and `token.pos_` (for part of speech). [Documentation here](https://spacy.io/api/token)